# Find strings that starts with #define and ends with \

Tags: awk, grep, patterns

I am trying to perform optimization of the macros definition in my C code. For the same I need to extract all the macros present in the C files and I need to find how many times this specific macro definition has been present.

The format of my macro definitions are in such a way that

```
#define MACRO_NAME DEFN_LINE1\
DEFN_LINE2\
DEFN_LINE3
```

So I thought my logic will be to

1. use regular expression to find the list of lines that starts with "#define" and ends with "\" redirect the above output to a file say MacroLineExtract.txt
2. remove all "#define " from MacroLineExtract.txt ==> MACRO_NAME DEFN_LINE1\
3. remove the trailing strings after the space ===> MACRO_NAME
4. save the above output to file Macros.txt which will now just hold the list of MACROS present in my code
5. Write a bash script to take one line after another from Macros.txt and find how many times that MACRO_NAME has appeared in my code.

Can you please help me in writing a regex/awk to find all the macros in my c files which starts with "#define" and ends with "\". If you have better logic please suggest the same.

Comment: `pcregrep -xo1 '#define\s+(\S+).*\\' file | pcregrep -rwFof - . | sort | uniq -c` ?

Comment: extend your input to contain more entries and show how should look the final result

Answer (score 2):

Using [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ ectags --c-kinds=d *.[ch]
```

`ectags` is enhanced version of `ctags` and `etags` used for creating a "tags file" which may be used by editors like Vi/Vim or Emacs for easy navigation of source code. It knows about C grammar rules so it is able to parse the C code for you (so that you don't need to worry about regular expressions).

With `--c-kinds=d` we tell `ectags` to only care about `#define` lines in C code.

You now have a file called `tags` in the current directory with the following kind of contents:

```
DEVELOPER       bayes.h 225;"   d
DIFFERENT       bayes.h 227;"   d
DIR_MIN bayes.h 338;"   d
DNA     bayes.h 242;"   d
DOLLAR  bayes.h 309;"   d
DOLLO   bayes.h 276;"   d
DOWN    bayes.h 215;"   d
```

That is, each line (except for a few header lines) identify the name of a macro, the source file where it was found, and the line number.  If a macro is defined in several files, it will be listed once for each occurrence.  The last `d` is a tags type indicator (these are all `#define`s).

If you just want the count of how many times each macro has been defined:

```
$ cut -f 1 tags | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do the parsing *and* counting in a single operation, assuming you can pass all the desired filenames without exceeding ARG_MAX:

```
awk '$1=="#define"&&/\\$/ {n[$2]++} END {for(i in n) print n[i],i}' *.[ch]

# this includes #define's that are indented with whitespace,
# which the C language allows. If you really want only #defines 
# that start exactly in column 1, use /^#define /&&/\\$/ 

# if you want the columns to line up change the print to something like
#   printf "%6d %s\n",x[i],i
```

Answer (score 0):

If lines are like these are in your file:

#define MACRO_NAME DEFN_LINE1\

then this will get the unique values for MACRO_NAME:

```
cat yourCfile | grep '#define' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u > macro_names
```

The grep is getting the lines containing '#define'

awk treats each string on a line as a new field, using space/spaces as the default field separator.  So here we just use awk to print the second field in "#define MACRO_NAME DEFN_LINE1\" which is "MACRO_NAME".

sort -u > macro_names just removes any duplicates and outputs everything to a file.

and to loop through your list of macro names and find how many lines contain that macro name:

```
for macro in $(cat macro_names); do
count=$(cat yourCfile | grep $macro | wc -l);
echo $macro appears $count times
done
```

the "wc" command with the "-l" flag prints the number of lines it receives from stdin.

Comment: `cat` not needed and `grep -c` can do the counting without a separate `wc -l`

Comment: ... And `grep x | awk '{y}'` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) which is better written `awk '/x/{y}'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot people. I used the solutions provided by you to craft to my needs. :)

```
awk '/#define.*\/$/{cnt[$2]++}END{for(i in cnt)print i}' > macro_names

#!/usr/local/bin/bash -x
TotalCount=0
CurrFileTotalCount=0
#takes One $macro after other from macro_names.txt file
for macro in $(cat macro_names); 
do
    #Takes $files from the current path in a recursive manner 
    #<$(find . -type f -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h")
    for files in $(find . -type f -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h")
    do
        #Counts the number of times $macro is present in $files
         CurrFileTotalCount=$(grep -c $macro "${files}");
         #Adds the Current file count to $TotalCount
         TotalCount=$(($TotalCount+$CurrFileTotalCount));
         #print the $CurrFileTotalCount and $TotalCount PROPERLY
    done 
    #Expected to print how many times that $macro is present in the files -- BUT PRINTS $TotalCount AS 0
    echo $macro appears_3 TotalCount $TotalCount
    TotalCount=0;
done
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sed '/#define/,\
        /^\(.*[^\]\)*$/N
        /\n\\/P;D'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it isn’t very useful by itself. Explaining *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the usefulness and long-term value of the answer.

Comment: @anthony to do for me that much is a challenge lately; in as little as a year i have severally relocated, been defenstrated, attacked with knives, fists and fictions, my home blazed and razed to ground, my belongings were destroyed, dispersed and distanced. i ought to have a nobel, but i still try to help. cheers,